# Testing Angular factory that wraps the external function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

My angular factory wraps the external function:

```
var External = function(){};

angular.module('app', [])
  .factory('ExternalWrap', function() {
    Object.defineProperty(External.prototype, '$id', {
      get: function() {
        return this.$$id === undefined || this.$$id === null ? this.id : this.$$id;
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.$$id = value;
      },
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: false
    });

    return External;
  });
```

karma-jasmine tests:

```
describe('test', function () {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  it('should work', function() {
    inject(function(ExternalWrap) {
      expect(ExternalWrap).toBeDefined();
    });
  });

  it('should work too', function() {
    inject(function(ExternalWrap) {
      expect(ExternalWrap).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
});
```

In the second test I get an error `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $id`.
Is it possible to test without changing the `ExternalWrap` factory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `configurable: true`, so I guess the answer is 'no' if you want to leave that factory as is.

Comment: Thanks.I expect that it is possible to set up karma so that it refreshes the page before each test?

Comment: Not sure. I'd recommend you ask a new question regarding your Karma config issues.